# Error When Building AOT Mode, on my Custom NPM Library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I get an error when I `ng build --aot`.

The error message is:

```
"ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js"
"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'customlib' in 'D:\Project\test-app\'

Is Anything Wrong with my Library ?

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core               7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.9
@angular/cli                       7.3.9
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.9
@schematics/angular                7.3.9
@schematics/update                 0.13.9
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.2.4
webpack                            4.29.0

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent} from './mycomponent.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyComponentModule{ }`
```

Comment: Where is the custom lib use ?

Comment: same error here.